# Problema con array

Tags: angularjs, json, array, push

Tengo un  problema muy simple y raro en un array en el cual lo declaro por ej:

```
$scope.pactUpdates = [];
```

El problema es cuando hago un push sobre ese array y le quiero asignar el valor de un control que es vacio.

```
$scope.pactUpdates.push({'data1':$scope.data1,'data2':$scope.data2, 'data3':$scope.data3});
```

El problema es que si en el input `data1` no cargue nada, en el array me pushea de la siguiente manera:

```
{'data2':'hola1','data3':'hola2'}
```

Si hago un segundo push, sí me agrega completo el array por más que no haya cargado algun inputo con datos:

```
{'data1':'','data2':'hola1111','data3':'hola2222'}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?. Ya probe a los inputos ponerle un `ng-init=' '` para que por lo menos me tome algo vacío.

Comment: agregas el código completo o lo tenemos que adivinar???

Answer (score 1):

Ignoro lo que ocurre con el resto de tu código.

Con el código que sigue quiero mostrar que quizá haya una forma más limpia y dinámica de hacer lo que quieres.

En el ejemplo te crea un array con todos los inputs del formulario, tengan datos o no. Si no te interesan todos, puedes indicar con un nombre de clase u otro sólo aquellos que quieras.

El objeto se crea usando como llave la etiqueta `name` de cada input, y como valor la etiqueta `value` correspondiente:

```js
$(function() 
{
  var campos = {};
  $("#myForm").find(":input").each(function() 
  {
    campos[this.name] = $(this).val();
  });
  var obj = {campos: campos};
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="data0" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="data1" value="hola1" />
  <input type="text" name="data2" value="hola2" />
  <input type="text" name="data3" value="hola3" />
</form>
```

Comment: A. Cedano, ante que nada te agradezco la ayuda.
Yo no estoy trabajando con formularios, solo con controles (inputs) con angular.

todos ellos tienen su ng-model

Del lado del controller tengo el problema cuando le hago el $scope.dato1 por ej que me dice que es undefined .
Cuando yo limpio el control para un nuevo ingreso (haciendo $scope.dato1='';
la próxima carga ya me lo toma como vacio y no como undefined que es el problema que estoy teniendo...

Comment: @wagego  Entiendo. Entonces debiste poner la etiqueta `angular` a tu pregunta. No uso angular, pero como veo que usas jQuery, sería casi lo mismo, sería cuestión de identificar en jQuery los elementos que quieres incluir en el array o en el objeto y proceder como se explica en el código. Lo único que variará será quizá la forma de determinar el grupo de inputs que quieres en tu array.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es de logica, cuando creas un objeto en **angular** con valor `null` no lo va a tomar, propongo el siguiente codigo

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.pactUpdates = [];
      $scope.data = {'data2':'hola1','data3':'hola2'};
      console.log("valor de data" ,$scope.data);
      $scope.pactUpdates.push({
        data1 : ((typeof $scope.data.data1 === "undefined") ? "" :$scope.data.data1), 
        data2 : ((typeof $scope.data.data2 === "undefined") ? "" :$scope.data.data2), 
        data3 : ((typeof $scope.data.data3 === "undefined") ? "" :$scope.data.data3)
                        })
      
      
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <pre>{{pactUpdates | json}}</pre>
      </div>
```

Comment: Perfecto JackNavaRow.

En realidad yo le venia preguntando directo al $scope su valor cuando hacia el push. Entonces al ser undefined no me lo agregaba al array.

Ahora lo que voy a hacer es preguntar directo ahi, de la siguiente manera (ya lo probe y funciona)

$scope.pactUpdates.push({ 'acc':((typeof $scope.accountPactUpdate === "undefined") ? "": $scope.accountPactUpdate).... etc, etc